# Php character limiter with 20 chars

Tags: php

I have a variable something like this:-

```
$item = 'gl.sck?ejk/shkjfe$%8wehjdm$3uiqo9iy723';
```

I just want the first 20 characters. how to get them with all the symbols intact
something like this

```
$itme_after_limit_20 = 'gl.sck?ejk/shkjfe$%8';
```

Exactly 20 character including symbols.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: $small = substr($item, 0,20);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr()` like below:-

```
<?php

$item ='gl.sck?ejk/shkjfe$%8wehjdm$3uiqo9iy723';

echo $itme_after_limit_20 = substr($item,0,20);//'gl.sck?ejk/shkjfe$%8';
```

Output:-https://eval.in/758693

Reference:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try that..

```
substr(string,start,length)
```